# Pester: Use variables in -ForEach data driven tests with rich content

Tags: powershell, data-driven-tests, pester

I write a module used for powershell-wrapping a commandline tool.

For my tests I had some variables defined in BeforeAll. Those vars should help in feeding the command with desired params and check them against the expected result, f.i.

```
BeforeAll {
   $PORead=@{
      Name = "Paul"
      Permission ="Read"
      Inheritance = "ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles"
   }

   $POReadExp="-bla bla (bla:bla;fra:fra;tra:tra)"
}
```

Now I want to use these in an it segment to feed the function and check the result, like:

```
It "checks result" -ForEach (
  @{Param=$PORead;Expected=$POReadExp}
) {
   $result=FunctionCall -Parameter1 $Param
   $result | Should -Be $Expected
}
```

Note: This is actually no working code - just to make clear what I want.

The problem is, that $Param and $Expected are $null, thus the current value of $PORead and $POReadExp are not assigned to $Param and $Expected.
I made it easy to demonstrate the problem - in my code I use arrays in the -ForEach hash assigned to $Param and $Expected.

Using plain strings, there is no problem and everything works fine.
I could use plain text and than use som switch construct to match my strings with the according variables from BeforeAll{}, but I thought there must be a more elegant way.

Using standard hashtables, the variable substition works fine.

I'd appreciate any idea.

---

To clarify some things:

The solution of Mark works somehow, but it needs the $PORead and $POReadExp to be set outside the BeforeAll-block (if you want to use -ForEach), or within the BeforeAll-block, but in that case you only can use one argument.

My plan was a bit different, so I'm making my point a bit clearer:

In the BeforeAll-block I wanted a bunch of definitions for params and outcomes

```
BeforeAll {
   $PORead = @{
   Name = "Paul"
   Permission ="Read"
   Inheritance = "ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles"

   $PODelete = @{
   Name = "Paul"
   Permission ="Delete"
   Inheritance = "ThisFolderOnly"
   }

   $POReadResult = "add parameters"
   $PODeleteResult = "delete parameters"
}
```

Now I want to test a whole bunch of combinations, feeding different combinations to the function and checking, if the combination of results match:

```
It "Test if all combinations works" -ForEach(
   @{FunctionParam=$PORead;Expected=$POReadExp}
   @{FunctionParam=$PORead,$PORead;Expected=$POReadExp,$POReadExp}
   @{FunctionParam=$PORead,$PODelete,$PORead,$PORead;Expected=$PORead,$PORead,$PORead,$PODelete}
) {
  $result = Function-Call -Param $FunctionParam
  $wanted = $expected -join(" ")
  $result | Should -Be $wanted
}
```

I *can* realize this by placing the definitions out of any block, but it feels wrong in terms of pester coding guidelines.

Greets
Usul

Comment: Hi iRon,
trying using yielded the following error: A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, the Using variable is valid only if the script block is invoked on a remote computer.

Answer (score 2):

The scopes for how to set test data with Pester v5 are quite confusing. What I've found is that anything you set in a `BeforeAll` or `BeforeEach` is available within the `It`. However if you want to set values to the `-ForEach` (or its alias `-TestData`) you need to do it as part of or before the `It`, outside of the `BeforeEach` or `BeforeAll`.

As such I think your tests will work if you do this:

```
$PORead = @{
   Name = "Paul"
   Permission ="Read"
   Inheritance = "ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles"
}

$POReadExp = "-bla bla (bla:bla;fra:fra;tra:tra)"

It "checks result" -ForEach (
  @{Param=$PORead;Expected=$POReadExp}
) {
   $result=FunctionCall -Parameter1 $Param
   $result | Should -Be $Expected
}
```

Or alternatively (if you just need to perform a single test):

```
BeforeAll {
   $PORead=@{
      Name = "Paul"
      Permission ="Read"
      Inheritance = "ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles"
   }

   $POReadExp="-bla bla (bla:bla;fra:fra;tra:tra)"
}

It "checks result" {
   $result = FunctionCall -Parameter1 $PORead
   $result | Should -Be $POReadExp
}
```

If you want to avoid using a variable that is not within one of the Pester code blocks, then you should do this (which is in line with the examples given in the [Pester documentation on Data Driven Tests](https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/usage/data-driven-tests)):

```
It "checks result" -ForEach (
  @{
      Param = @{
          Name = "Paul"
          Permission = "Read"
          Inheritance = "ThisFolderSubfoldersAndFiles"
      }
      Expected = "-bla bla (bla:bla;fra:fra;tra:tra)"
  }) {
      $result=FunctionCall -Parameter1 $Param
      $result | Should -Be $Expected
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I didn't try this yet, but migrating to pester 5 I wanted to keep in track with the design guidelines for pester 5, telling that no code at all should be placed outside of a block. Your solution places code outside a block and that is the "$PORead=" line. 
I'll check if your solution works though.

Comment: And as I said before, in my code I use array: I want the function call to be fed with different combinations of the input parameters (like $PORead) and conduct the expected result by collecting the the different results (like $POReadExp), so that I can check, whether the combination of all given params works like desired, too.

Comment: The Pester guide on Data Driven Tests shows the data being directly provided to the `-ForEach` parameter on the `It`, but I don't think its bad practice to use a variable before the `It` block and then pass that variable instead, I personally think its better for readability. I'll add a 3rd example showing it being provided directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your data used to generate tests from the BeforEach{} block to [BeforeDiscovery{}](https://pester.dev/docs/usage/data-driven-tests#beforediscovery) block (see the linked pester documentation, has a really good simple example).

Pester needs your data that drives your DataDrivenTests to be available before it dynamically generates the test cases, so it knows how many to make.

BeforeAll{}/BeforeEach{} blocks should be reserved for data used after the It{} blocks are generated, but before they are evaluated.